# Error Casting in Java

Tags: java, casting

I have the next problem:

I am making a simple cast:

```
TargetBot2Params params = (TargetBot2Params)bot.getParams();
```

But I get the next error:

```
Inconvertible types
  Requiered: TargetBot2Params
  Found: UT2004BotParameters
```

And I dont know why occurs this, because I think that it doesnt do the cast.

Anyone knows why occurs this?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says it all.

For the casting to be successful, `UT2004BotParameters` has to either be a `TargetBot2Params` (i.e., *extends* `TargetBot2Params`) or, if `TargetBot2Params` is an interface, *implement* it.